# Remote desktop connection conundrum

Tags: ms-access, remote-access, remote-desktop

i may be going about this the wrong way and would appreciate guidance on how it should be done. :)

I have a windows 7 computer on which i have installed thinVNC ([Remote desktop application](http://www.cybelesoft.com/thinfinity/remote-desktop/workstation))

i liked it because its cross platform and does not need the clients to install anything on their devices to connect to the computer.They simply use a HTML 5 enabled browser to connect.

The purpose of this is so that they can get to a Microsoft access database on the computer, log in to it and perform some transactions.

Now, when one person logs in they see the desktop and interact with it and thats fine. However, when another person connects to the computer, they basically watch as the first user goes about using the database. Which i think is the purpose of this kind of software!

So i guess what i want is that each user gets their own fresh "session" if you like, like having the file on a network drive. So users connect to the computer,don't see others using the system and there's a folder where i have granted access to external users and placed the database in it. They will then doubleclick the file icon and be able to login etc.

So what is the best way to achieve this? ideally i don't want the user to have to install any software to be able to connect, but if its unavoidable then so be it.

thanks

Comment: As i know concurrent sessions is a feature of microsoft's server OS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Microsoft's built in remote desktop? There's a version for most (if not all) devices now and it would let you just setup multiple accounts on the Win 7 pc and get each user to log into them individually.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. i did try that but only one user can log in at a time. The current user must disconnect for another to connect and i may be wrong but i think the other client has to be a windows machine. cheers

Comment: There are clients for RDP protocol(ms remote desktop) at any OS. But again, concurrent sessions exists only at server editions of microsoft OS. (yes, you can turn it on at any ms OS with a little hack, but this is illegal)